# Use gsub in R to remove / and replace with nothing

Tags: r, gsub

I have a data frame, which I have called rawdata.df, that looks similar to this:

```
Sample_ID Barcode DQ789028 DQ404151 EF042091 EF034081
4313715   4313715 A/A      C/C      C/G      A/T
4313716   4313716 C/C      A/C      G/G      T/T
```

I want to use the gsub function in R to remove the / from all instances

```
newdata.df <- gsub("/", "", rawdata.df)
```

What I get is:

```
[1] "1:2"     "1:2"     "1:2"     "c(2, 1)" "1:2"     "1:2"
```

Comment: Another way would be `df[-(1:2)] <- gsub("[/]", "",unlist(df[,-(1:2)]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (assuming your data.frame is `df`):

```
> df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub("/", "", x))
> df
#  Sample_ID Barcode DQ789028 DQ404151 EF042091 EF034081
#1   4313715 4313715       AA       CC       CG       AT
#2   4313716 4313716       CC       AC       GG       TT
```

Comment: I would just add one tiny detail to the function to avoid unwanted coercions: `if (is.character(x)) gsub("/", "", x) else x`.

Comment: What exactly is     df[] doing?

Comment: It makes sure that the structure (data.frame) is kept in df. Otherwise df would be turned into a list because the default output of lapply is a list.

Comment: @beginneR: if you wrapped the lapply in data.frame(), would that not return a data frame?  I.e., df <- data.frame(lapply .....